# How to gsub all multiple whitespaces in dataframe through a single space in R

Tags: r, dataframe, whitespace, gsub

i want to replace all multiple whitespaces through a single space in a whole dataframe.

i.E.

```
v1 <- c("Aluminium           ,          Kunststoff", "Kunststoff       ,     Stahl     ,    Stoff")
v2 <- c("230      V", "    24      W")
df <- data.frame(v1, v2)
```

The result should be:

```
                     v1        v2
1 Aluminium , Kunststoff       230 V
2 Kunststoff , Stahl , Stoff   24 W
```

I've tried this, but it dosen't work:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
                  gsub(" {2,}", " ", x)
              }))
```

It would of course be optimal if there were no spaces before a comma. Otherwise I would have done that in the next step.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s+", " ", x))`

Comment: Oh, is it really that simple?!

Comment: Or, try `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s*(,)\\s*|\\s+", "\\1 ", x))` to have `,` with one space after in the replacement. Or do you want to get `Aluminium,Kunststoff` as output?

Answer (score 2):

If your dataframe columns are of character type, and you need to replaces any one or more whitespace chunks with a single space, you can use

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s+", " ", x))
```

To remove spaces before a comma, and keep a single space after a comma, you can use

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s*(,)\\s*|\\s+", "\\1 ", x))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wcQRHE/1). `\s*(,)\s*|\s+` matches either zero or more whitespaces, a comma (captued into Group 1) and zero or more whitespace, or one or more whitespaces, and replaces the matches with Group 1 + a literal space.

To remove spaces around commas, you can use

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s*(,)\\s*|(\\s)+", "\\1\\2", x))
```

NOTE: with this last example, the space used as a substitution char for multiple whitespace chunks will be the last whitespace char in the chunk.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wcQRHE/2). The regex is similar to the one above, but the last `\s` is captured into Group 2 and used in a so-called ["repeated capturing group"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) where only the last value captured is saved in the group.

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/dgZe49):

```r
v1 <- c("Aluminium           ,          Kunststoff", "Kunststoff       ,     Stahl     ,    Stoff")
v2 <- c("230      V", "    24      W")
df <- data.frame(v1, v2)

lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s+", " ", x))
## => [1] "Aluminium , Kunststoff"     "Kunststoff , Stahl , Stoff"
###   [1] "230 V" " 24 W"
lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s*(,)\\s*|\\s+", "\\1 ", x))
## => [1] "Aluminium, Kunststoff"     "Kunststoff, Stahl, Stoff"
###   [1] "230 V" " 24 W"
lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\s*(,)\\s*|(\\s)+", "\\1\\2", x))
## => [1] "Aluminium,Kunststoff"     "Kunststoff,Stahl,Stoff"
###   [1] "230 V" " 24 W"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)
df = sapply(df, function(x) str_replace_all(x, "\\s+", " "))
df
```

```
     v1                           v2     
[1,] "Aluminium , Kunststoff"     "230 V"
[2,] "Kunststoff , Stahl , Stoff" " 24 W"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~gsub("\\s{2,},\\s{2,}", ", ", .)))
                        v1            v2
1    Aluminium, Kunststoff    230      V
2 Kunststoff, Stahl, Stoff     24      W
```